# Pascal beginner program

Tags: pascal, freepascal

```
Program q2;


Var input: integer ;
Var repeatvar: char ;



Procedure display(input : integer) ;



Begin
If (input = 9) then 
  Write ('********************************************************') ;
  Write ('9! = 9 x 8 x 7 x 6 x 5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 = 362880 ');
  Write ('********************************************************') ;    
If (input = 8) then
  Write ('********************************************************') ;
  Write ('8! = 8 x 7 x 6 x 5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 = 40320 ');
  Write ('********************************************************') ;
If (input = 7) then
  Write ('********************************************************') ;
  Write ('7! = 7 x 6 x 5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 = 5040 ');
  Write ('********************************************************') ;
If (input = 6) then
  Write ('********************************************************') ;
  Write ('6! = 6 x 5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 = 720 ');
  Write ('********************************************************') ;
If (input = 5) then
  Write ('********************************************************') ;
  Write ('5! = 5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 = 120 ');
  Write ('********************************************************') ;
If (input = 4) then
  Write ('********************************************************') ;
  Write ('4! = 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 = 24 ');
  Write ('********************************************************') ;
If (input = 3) then
  Write ('********************************************************') ;
  Write ('3! = 3 x 2 x 1 = 6 ');
  Write ('********************************************************') ;
If (input = 2) then
  Write ('********************************************************') ;
  Write ('2! = 2 x 1 = 2 ');
  Write ('********************************************************') ;
If (input = 1) then
  Write ('********************************************************') ;
  Write ('1! = 1 = 1 ');
  Write ('********************************************************') ;
If (input = 0) then
  Write ('********************************************************') ;
  Write ('0! = 1 = 1 ');
  Write ('********************************************************') ;

End ;


Begin

While (repeatvar = 'y') do
Begin
Write('Enter an integer between 0 and 9 or -1 to quit');
readln(input);

If (input = -1) then
  begin
  Write('Sentinel value - Exiting program !'); 
  Readln;
  end
Else
  display(input);

End 


End.
```

This is the warning I get after compiling it .

```
Free Pascal Compiler version 2.4.0 [2010/05/18] for x86_64
Copyright (c) 1993-2009 by Florian Klaempfl
Target OS: Linux for x86-64
Compiling q2.pas
q2.pas(61,8) Warning: Variable "repeatvar" does not seem to be initialized
Linking q2
/usr/bin/ld: warning: link.res contains output sections; did you forget -T?
78 lines compiled, 0.2 sec
1 warning(s) issued
```

I am typing in q2 but cannot see any output , it's not doing anything. I have tried a number of things , also I am totally new to Pascal , and fpc . Can anyone tell me what's the problem ?

In the part of the     repeatvar , i wanted to implement this :

i wanted to implement this c++ code :

```
do
{
    cout << "Enter an integer between 0 and 9 or -1 to quit => " ;
    cin >> input ; // get number 
    if(input == -1)
    {
        cout << "Sentinel value - Exiting program !" << endl;
        exit ;
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {

    // display function
    display(input) ;
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << " Press y to repeat , any other key and enter to terminate: " ;
    cin >> repeat ;
    if(repeat != 'y')
        exit;

}while( repeat == 'y');
```

Comment: ASk your self this : What is the Value of `repeatvar` at this line the very first time you get to the line : `While (repeatvar = 'y') do`. Ask yourself what the test is checking for and what you're giving it. ie **when is this line FIRST executed and when do you ask for input!**

Comment: i wanted to implement this c++ code !! , the one i edited . please have a look @PreetSangha . I am relatively new to programming , so the logic is a bit wayward.

Comment: possible duplicate of [c++ to pascal conversion of a beginner program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14553469/c-to-pascal-conversion-of-a-beginner-program). Do not post the same question again as a new one when your question is closed. Instead, improve the closed question and ask for it to be reopened. Reposting it as a duplicate is a violation of this site's guidelines.

Comment: ok , will keep that in mind . Am sorry about that. Am new to this site. thnx ! @KenWhite - how should I ask to reopen my previous question ?

Comment: The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) has information about why questions are closed and what you should do. (The basic method, however, is to edit your question to improve it; once you do that, it typically gets reopened without any need to do anything else.)

Comment: Where is the equivalent of cin >> repeat; in your program?

Comment: Please do not edit your questions like that, because that makes existing comments/answers/suggestions simply nonsensical. If you have another question, please post it as a *new* question.

Answer (score 2):

Because the repeatvar is never initialized, your program never enters the while loop, because there is no way for repeatvar to be 'y' to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to initialize the variable

```
repeatvar := 'y'
```

insert the above line before the lines

```
While (repeatvar = 'y') do 
Begin

...

End
```

Answer (score -1):

i hope that the correction of code

```
program Project1;


Var input: integer ;
Var repeatvar: char ;



Procedure display(input : integer) ;
Begin
If (input = 9) then
  begin
  Writeln ('********************************************************') ;
  Writeln ('9! = 9 x 8 x 7 x 6 x 5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 = 362880 ');
  Writeln ('********************************************************') ;
  end;
If (input = 8) then
  begin
  Writeln ('********************************************************') ;
  Writeln ('8! = 8 x 7 x 6 x 5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 = 40320 ');
  Writeln ('********************************************************') ;
  end;
If (input = 7) then
  begin
  Writeln ('********************************************************') ;
  Writeln ('7! = 7 x 6 x 5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 = 5040 ');
  Writeln ('********************************************************') ;
  end;
If (input = 6) then
  begin
  Writeln ('********************************************************') ;
  Writeln ('6! = 6 x 5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 = 720 ');
  Writeln ('********************************************************') ;
  end;
If (input = 5) then
  begin
  Writeln ('********************************************************') ;
  Writeln ('5! = 5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 = 120 ');
  Writeln ('********************************************************') ;
  end;
If (input = 4) then
  begin
  Writeln ('********************************************************') ;
  Writeln ('4! = 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 = 24 ');
  Writeln ('********************************************************') ;
  end;
If (input = 3) then
  begin
  Writeln ('********************************************************') ;
  Writeln ('3! = 3 x 2 x 1 = 6 ');
  Writeln ('********************************************************') ;
  end;
If (input = 2) then
  begin
  Writeln ('********************************************************') ;
  Writeln ('2! = 2 x 1 = 2 ');
  Writeln ('********************************************************') ;
  end;
If (input = 1) then
  begin
  Writeln ('********************************************************') ;
  Writeln ('1! = 1 = 1 ');
  Writeln ('********************************************************') ;
  end;
If (input = 0) then
begin
  Writeln ('********************************************************') ;
  Writeln ('0! = 1 = 1 ');
  Writeln ('********************************************************') ;
  end;
End ;


Begin
repeat
   writeln('enter number between 1-9 or -1 to quit: ');
   readln(input);
   display(input);
until input=-1;


End.
```